# Recursion with matrix determinant

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, matrix

I'm working on making a Matrix class in java and all I have left to do is add in a function for the determinant and inverse. I've never had to use recursion before and after looking through various sources I still am struggling to implement it into my algorithm. I want to write the algorithm myself without using code from the internet but when I look at how they implement recursion into their algorithm I still don't understand how to add it to mine.

```
public double determinent() {
    if(isSquareMatrix(this)) {
        if(row > 2) {
            for(int r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
                for(int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                    double[][] m = new double[row-1][col-1];
                    int tr = 0;
                    int tc = 0;
                    for(int rm1 = 0; rm1 < row; rm1++) {
                        for(int cm1 = 0; cm1 < col; cm1++) {
                            if(rm1 != 0 && cm1 != c) {
                                m[tr][tc++] = matrix[rm1][cm1];
                            }
                        }
                        if(rm1 != 0) {
                            tr++;
                        }
                        tc = 0;
                    }
                    Matrix m1 = new Matrix(m);
                    double scalar = matrix[r][c];
                    double sign = r+c % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1; // add or subtract
                    m1 = m1.multiplyByScalar(sign * scalar);
                    m1.determinent(0);
                }
            } 
        } else {
            // This is where recursion would occur
            return matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1];
        }
    } else {
        throw new SizeDoesntMatchException("Error: Not a square matrix");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, why you set r in a for-loop: `for (int r = 0; r < 1; r++)`?

Comment: Why recursion? You can calculate a determinant easily (and efficiently) from the LU decomposition, which you'd implement anyway to do a solve or to calculate an explicit inverse

Comment: Consider posting [mcve] with test data

Comment: The way you'd define something mathematically or compute it by hand is often NOT the best way to compute it with a machine. Cofactors and minors are a bad algorithm for determinants. Run time with a naive implementation like yours is O(n!).  Moreover, matrix inverse and determinant are very seldom needed to solve real numerical problems. It's almost always a mistake to use them. When they are required, the same factorization methods that _are_ best used to solve linear numerical problems also provide the inverse and determinant. Get a good text on numerical linear algebra and do some reading.